# "Talk In Chat" privilege without enough points

Tags: support, privileges

I recently got the [Talk In Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) privilege which you normally receive at 20 reputation, but for some reason I got it at 18.

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you still have the privilege? Maybe someone upvoted one of your posts, bringing you above 20 points... then un-upvoted it, bringing you below again.

Comment: You don't have anymore, [it's gone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkJqKOb0ZhY).

Comment: oh wow its gone again @S.L.Barth hehe

Comment: The [0 in your net reputation change](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6488337/kevin-seda?tab=reputation) shows something was reversed e.g. an upvote/unupvote, accept, unaccept etc.

Comment: Post good questions or answers on the main site. You'll break through 20 points again, and the chat privilege will return. In a more permanent way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look at your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6488337/kevin-seda?tab=reputation), I see an entry for today:

> There were no net reputation changes on this day

The keyword here is *net*. This means that today, you had something that was reversed. Someone upvoted a post of yours, then un-upvoted it again. Or maybe an upvoted post of yours was deleted.

At any rate, it looks like you were at or above 20 points for a short time, and are now back below 20.